# ViewChildren passing multiple components

Tags: angular

Why can't I pass multiple components within the @ViewChildren?

Currently have this:

```ts
 @ViewChildren(ColorFilterComponent, TransmissionFilterComponent)
 public filters: QueryList<Filter>;
```

Both components implements my Filter interface:

```ts
export declare abstract class Filter {
    abstract applyFilter(vehicles: Vehicle): boolean;
}
```

At a certain point I am iterating through `filters` and calling `applyFilter()` method for all components within the viewChildren.

However when I do a simple log:

```ts
console.log(this.filters.toArray());
```

It contains only one filter. The other one is not here.

What would be a good best practice in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <colorfilter #filter></as-colorfilter>
 <transmissionfilter #filter></as-transmissionfilter>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChildren('filter')
public filters: QueryList<Filter>;
```

Answer (score 5):

This is only supported with template variables

```ts
@ViewChildren('var1,var2,var3')
```

but not with component or directive types.

If `Filter` is a common base class, you can try something like:

```ts
providers: [{ 
  provide: Filter, 
  useExisting: [ColorFilterComponent, TransmissionFilterComponent],
  multi: true
}]
```

and then query like

```ts
@ViewChildren(Filter) filters: QueryList<Filter>;
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8580#issuecomment-218331920

Comment: that's not the answer I am looking for. Is there a different solution for this case?

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't tried this myself yet. Especially not with 'multi: true`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Found the solution on the link you provided. See my answer.