# Inject AbstractControlDirective instance as @ContentChild to custom directive

Tags: angular, directive, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have form control like this:

```
<input formControlName="myName" dynamicDisable>
```

Then a custom directive:

```
 @Directive({
    selector: '[formControlName][dynamicDisable]
 })
 export class DynamicDisableDirective implements AfterContentInit {

      @ContentChild(AbstractControlDirective) control: any;

      ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        console.log(this.control);
      }
    }
```

I would like to inject the directive owner element as a @ContentChild to the directive. Owner elements can be any type of form control, like simple FormControl, FormGroup or even FormArray. FormControlName is a descendant of AbstractControlDirective. Why the console always logs 'undefined' then?

Note: when I switch AbstractControlDirective for NgControl like this:

```
@ContentChild(NgControl) control: any;
```

everything works as expected, the form control instance gets injected and logged well. However, this approach can be used only for simple FormControl, not also groups and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is nothing provided as `AbstractControlDirective`, therefore querying or injecting one will not work without further assistance.

I haven't tried, but it might work to register alias providers like

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: '[formControlName][dynamicDisable],
    providers: [
     { provide: AbstractControlDirective, useExisting: FormControl, useMulti: true },
     { provide: AbstractControlDirective, useExisting: FormGroup, useMulti: true },
    ]
})
```

With `useMulti: true` you are able to (to all of them), to get a list if there are more than one that match and then filter the list for what you actually want.

Comment: If I provide the AbstractControlDirective like this I receive this error: `core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for FormGroup!`

Comment: I see. I guess you must use `useMulti` then.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if this can work. The approach came from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366869/viewchildren-passing-multiple-components/39366891#39366891. Another approach would be to inject or query for each of them (using the concrete class) and check which one was found.

Comment: `useMulti` won't get compiled, it was probably deprecated (v4.3.3) and now we need to use just `multi`. However it did not help, same error.

Comment: I am using the second approach you mentioned but it is a lot of code, it would be nicer if I can use just the common abstract class.

Comment: If the approach with `useMulti` doesn't work, there is probably no way to do that. DI doesn't maintain or process information about subclasses. (`@ViewChild` and `@ContentChild` are also based on DI)